# Exploding comma deliminated CSV file when column values itself contains comma

Tags: php, csv, explode

I am reading a comma deliminated CSV file line by line and then separate each column value using PHP **explode** function. The problem is that there are some columns which itself have **comma (,)** values in it so they are also exploded.

A row of data:

```
03,1392,06,1000,1,"1000,36,21,68",4,AF,TJ,AF,44071000
```

Here **"1000,36,21,68"** must be considered as a single value but PHP explode also breaks it. I know this is how explode works but is there any alternate function which can be used in this case. Also i would need to remove the **double quotes (")** from both sides from this value.

Comment: Or http://php.net/fgetcsv if you are reading from file.

Comment: or [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg-split)

Comment: @hal9000 preg_split appears to be good idea, what should be the regex in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try using explode and parsing it yourself:

use PHP's built-in [str_getcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) function

or use [fgetcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) to read and parse each line directly from file

**EDIT**

If you're feeling really adventurous, you can use SPL to read and parse the file

```
$file = new SplFileObject("data.csv");
while (!$file->eof()) {
    var_dump($file->fgetcsv());
}
```

or

```
$file = new SplFileObject("data.csv");
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
foreach ($file as $fields) {
    var_dump($fields);
}
```

Comment: Great It works! I am using fopen and fgets to read each line. Is fopen better or SplFileObject?

Comment: I tend to use SplFileObject because it gives a degree cleaner coding when setting flags to manipulate the way the file is parsed, but fopen() and fgetcsv() is really just as easy to code